# What materials transport/refract UV-C radiation

Tags: material-science, radiation, optical-materials

I was reading about UV-C radiation for germicidal applications and thought about how easily it is blocked by most plastics/glass. My question is, is there a material that doesn't block the UV-C light, but carries/refracts it like those old fiber-optic toys?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quartz glass is the usual means for transparency for UV, you find the adsorption easily  per google.